# Как получить все пакеты между моим хостом и определенным сайтом?

Tags: wireshark

Как с помощью wireshark взять все пакеты предназначенные для определенного сайта?

Например, для www.gmail.com. Если я смотрю через nslookup то мне выдается 4 разных адреса gmail, но это пол-беды, через некоторое время gmail выдает пачку уже из  других четырех адресов. То есть ip.dst=XX.XX.XX.XX и так 4 или 8 раз - это не вариант, как мне кажется.

Как найти все пакеты с которыми обменивался мой компьютер  с gmail.com ? (все пакеты - от начала запроса DNS и т.д. при условии что ip адрес gmail мог меняться в теч времени).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуете dns.qry.name contains "gmail.com"

Comment: это только пакеты про DNS, а как взять все пакеты ?